# How to disable and enable button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am currently building a shopping list app that contains a form, input box and submit button. My goal is to allow the user to input values into the form up until there has been 6 items listed on the page; after it has reached 6, I would like to disable the button so that no more values can be added. However, if a user deletes an item (e.g. the list goes down to 5 items), I would like for the button to be enabled until it reaches 6 and then continue the same routine over again.

I have tried to use an array and an "if else if statement" specifying the conditions, but that has not worked. Below is the JS code that I have tried.

```
let items = [];

      let list = document.querySelector('ul');

      let input = document.querySelector('input');
      let button = document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', buttonClick);

    function buttonClick() {

    let myItem = input.value;

    console.log(items)

    items.push(input.value);

    input.value = '';



    if (items.length === 6) {

     let e = document.querySelector('button').disabled = true;

     items.length = 0;

    } else if (button.disabled === false) {

      button.disabled = true;

    }
```

Here is the HTML

```
<img src='img/paper.jpg'>


<div class='second'>
  <label for="item">Enter a new item:</label>
  <input type="text" name="item" id="item">
  <button>Add item</button>
</div>
<ul>

</ul>
</div>
```

I continue to receive an error message on the console stating, "Cannot read property disabled of undefined".

Comment: Add html into your question

Comment: in which line 
1. when you assigning it as true
2. Or. when you checking it with if statement

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change this line of your code

```
let button = document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', buttonClick);
```

To this one

```
let button = document.querySelector('button');
button = .addEventListener('click', buttonClick);
```

And then you can make it disabled or not without selecting it again

```
button.disabled = true or button.disabled = false
```

Comment: there is no such code. What I want to say is when select your button on top with let button = document.querySelector('button'). You may use this button variable. Your code => let e = document.querySelector('button').disabled = true; you can change let e = button.disabled = true;

Answer (score 0):

Your need to get your button by id.

Change this:

```
 let e = document.querySelector('button').disabled = true;
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById("ID_OF_BUTTON").disabled = true;
```

Remember to change "ID_OF_BUTTON" to id you put on your button html.

Comment: you can select by tag name with document.querySelector(). No need for id if there is only one button

Answer (score 0):

I think chaining the method in below code is causing the issue:

```
let button = document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', buttonClick);
```

**Solution:**

1.First get the button control:

```
let button=document.querySelector('button');
```

2.Attach event handlor.

```
button.addEventListener('click',buttonClick);
```